# show description of marker in problemview/marker view when click on perticular custom marker on vertical ruler of eclipse default editor

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde

I am new to eclipse plugin development ,I am developing eclipse plugin  for displaying custom marker on vertical ruler of the eclipse default editor . I am done with that part  which put markers on the line numbers in eclipse editor.

This is type of problem marker .all goes fine but how to display its description in problem view/marker view.

If somebody is having some ideas please share.

Answer (score 0):

You can find more details about the linkage to problem views in the following tutorial.
http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Mark%20My%20Words/mark-my-words.html